# Jqgrid Client Side Sorting and Server Side Paging

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, service, jqgrid

How to achieve Client Side Sorting and Server Side Paging in Jgrid .

Output is Json Response container 10 record out of 1000 . So my query is that want to sort only 10 record that are display on current page. Not all record should be sorted.

Please find the code below :

```
    jQuery("#SubConGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: '',
    height: 230,
    width: 300,
    colNames: ['SubcontractorID', 'Name', 'Type', 'RCBCode'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'SubcontractorID', index: 'SubcontractorID', width: 100, sortable: false, hidden: true },
    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, sorttype: "text", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "SelectContractor('", addParam: "');"} },
    { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', sorttype: "text", width: 50 },
    { name: 'RCBCode', index: 'RCBCode', width: 50, sorttype: "text" },
],
    multiselect: false,
    caption: "SubContractor",
    pager: jQuery('#pageNavigation'),
    viewrecords: true,
    scrollrows: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    sortable: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    rowList: [10, 15, 20],
    pgbuttons: true,
    pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
    altRows: true,
    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        GetSearchData();
    }
});



function GetSearchData() {
  PageMethods.GetSubContractorSearch( $("#SubConGrid").getGridParam("page"), 
                 $(".ui-pg-selbox").val(), onGetListSuccess, onError);
}
```

Comment: Sorry the title is Jqgrid